# When using a component (depending on it) its dependencyManagement is not reflected

Tags: maven, dependency-management

If I have a component called say dev.comps:comp1 that has org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0 in the dependencyManagement, when I build comp1 then commons-text:1.10.0 will be used even though one of its transitive dependencies might be for commons-text:1.9.

If I have another component call dev.apps:app1 that depends on comp1, when I build app1 then org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9 will be used as the dependencyManagement in comp1 is not used or respected.

See [branch DEPEDENCY_MANAGEMENT in GIT repo](https://github.com/marioja/sample-tests/tree/DEPENDENCY_MANAGEMENT) for an illustration.

Is this a FEATURE or a BUG.

Comment: (it is in the details, but) of course will app1 [resolve dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) in his *own way*, not/only transitively considering comp1's dependencyManagement. `<dependencyManagement>` 
 *can* be [inherited](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#inheritance)/[imported](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#importing-dependencies)...but not via "normal dependency"... (and since so many reputable oss projects do so, i tend to say: it is feature:)

Comment: in your sample it really looks like a bug! :)) ..please experiment: when you "add explicit dependency" (with/-out version/dependencyManagement)